# Regular Expression to a Java.regex.Pattern

Tags: java, regex

I'm working with the IPV6 address space to have our java app accept the IPV6 standard. I've written a regular expression that is tested and working.

```
((([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){7}([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){6}(:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3})|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){5}((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,2}|:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3})|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){4}((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,3})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:)|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){3}|(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,2}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){2}((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,5})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,3}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:)|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){1}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,6})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,4}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,7}|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,5}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9}?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3})|:))
```

Can anyone tell me how to get this working with the proper escapes to compile as a Java pattern?

Comment: How did you test this? Not in Java?

Comment: and now you have two problems :)

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
Pattern.compile("((([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){7}([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){6}(:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|1\\d\\d|[1-9]?\\d)(\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|1\\d\\d|[1-9]?\\d)){3})|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){5}((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,2}|:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|1\\d\\d|[1-9]?\\d)(\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|1\\d\\d|[1-9]?\\d)){3})|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){4}((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,3})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|1\\d\\d|[1-9]?\\d)(\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|1\\d\\d|[1-9]?\\d)){3}))|:)|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){3}|(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,2}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|1\\d\\d|[1-9]?\\d)(\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|1\\d\\d|[1-9]?\\d)){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){2}((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,5})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,3}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|1\\d\\d|[1-9]?\\d)(\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|1\\d\\d|[1-9]?\\d)){3}))|:)|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){1}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,6})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,4}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|1\\d\\d|[1-9]?\\d)(\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|1\\d\\d|[1-9]?\\d)){3}))|:))|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,7}|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,5}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|1\\d\\d|[1-9]?\\d)(\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|1\\d\\d|[1-9]?\\d)){3})|:)))")
```

Summary of changes:

- All backslashes are doubled.
- There is a typo of `[1-9}` in your pattern. That is fixed.
- Your pattern is also missing a final closing parenthesis.

Comment: @Alan: Indeed. All I did was load up the regex using `Pattern.compile` (in JRuby, so I can use single-quoted strings and thus not get stung on the single backslashes), and keep fixing the pattern until the `compile` call returns successfully. :-)

Comment: Chris this works wonderfully with a clean pattern compile. Appreciate the quick accurate reply. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to escape in order to make this regular expression works. You can check "Escape Sequence" section of this tutorial for better explaination

[Characters](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the official API docs, specifically the [Pattern class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) (which has a list of escape characters, and other stuff specific to the Java implementation of Regex), and the [java.util.regex package documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html) in general.

[This site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) has been one of my favorites for regex reference, and has some details on some of the Java-specific regex quirks.

Comment: Thank you but I did actually view those exact sites. I think Chris's suggest might do the trick.